# How to implement super mechanism in javascript through prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I am struggling to understand the constructor invocation pattern in Javascript. 
I have a base object  `Mammal` ( would it be incorrect to use the term *class* ? )  and an inherited object `Cat`. In the following code the object `Cat` correctly inherits from the Mammal object.

```
/* 
  Mammal base Object 
*/

var Mammal = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}  

Mammal.prototype.get_name = function() {
  return this.name;    
} 

Mammal.prototype.says = function () {
  return this.saying || ''; 
} 

/*
  Cat object 
*/

var Cat = function (name) {
  this.saying = "Meow";  
  this.name = name; 
}

Cat.prototype.purr = function (number) {

  var i =0, s=''; 

  for ( i=0; i<number; i++)
     if (s)   
       s +='-'; 
     s+='r'; 

  return s;  
}

Cat.prototype = new Mammal(); 

console.log("Pseudo classical inheritance approach"); 
var mammal = new Mammal(" I am a mammal"); 
console.log("Who are you ? " + mammal.get_name()); 
console.log("What are you saying? " + mammal.says()); 

var cat = new Cat('I am a cat'); 
console.log("Who are you ? " + cat.get_name()); 
console.log("What are you saying? " + cat.says());
```

What I don't like in this pattern is how the constructor of the base object is used. The object `Cat` does not reuse correctly the constructor of the base class `Mammal`. I would like to have a more flexibility. Each time a `Cat` object is created, the constructor of the `Mammal` object is invoked with no arguments. I would like to use a mechanism similar to the "super" keyword in Java, so that when the constructor of `Cat` is called with `name` as parameter, also the constructor of `Mammal` is called with `name` as parameter.

I tried to implement the `Cat` constructor as follows :

```
  var Cat = function (name) {
      this.saying = "Meow";  
      // Super (name);
      this.prototype = new Mammal(name); 
    }
```

This does not work as expected. `this.prototype` is undefined. why? Why this approach is completely wrong? does `this` point to the newly `Cat` object?

I know, there are different ways to implement inheritance in javaScript, but I am wondering if there is a way to implement the super mechanism like in Java.

Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid that's not how you set up hierarchies. It's close, but there are a couple of key issues. (One of which — calling `new Mammal()` to create `Cat.prototype` — is a very, very, very frequent error you see in a lot of blog posts and such.)

Here's a simple example of doing it correctly:

```
// A function to set up the link between a child and parent
function derive(Child, Parent) {
    // `ctor` is a temporary function we use so we can get an object
    // backed by `Parent.prototype` but without calling `Parent`.
    function ctor() { }

    // Borrow the prototype
    ctor.prototype = Parent.prototype;

    // Create an object backed by `Parent.prototype` and use it as
    // `Child`'s prototype
    Child.prototype = new ctor();

    // Some housekeeping to make the prototype look like the ones
    // the JavaScript engine creates normally.
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

    // Note: If we can rely on ES5 features, we could use
    // `Object.create` instead of the `ctor` function.
}

// The parent constructor    
var Mammal = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

// Some stuff for its prototype
Mammal.prototype.get_name = function() {
  return this.name;    
};

Mammal.prototype.says = function () {
  return this.saying || ''; 
};

// The child constructor    
var Cat = function(name) {
  Mammal.call(this, name);
  this.saying = "Meow";  
};

// Hook it up to the parent
derive(Cat, Mammal);

// Add some things to its prototype
Cat.prototype.purr = function (number) {

  var i =0, s=''; 

  for ( i=0; i<number; i++)
     if (s)   
       s +='-'; 
     s+='r'; 

  return s;  
};
```

If you're interested in doing inheritance hierarchies in JavaScript, you may find my [`Lineage` script](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs) useful. You may or may not choose to use it, but it demonstrates how to set things up, a way to do calls to the parent's version of methods ("supercalls"), etc. In particular, [this documentation page](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript#3_-_Plain_JavaScript) comparing using `Lineage` to not using it shows how to do this without any helper script. But there's a reason I wrote a helper script to do it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
var Cat = function (name) {
  this.saying = "Meow";  
  // Super (name);
  Mammal.call( this, name );
}
```

Comment: using this mechanism the Cat object does NOT inherit from the Mammal Object. Right?

Comment: It does if you keep the rest of your code. You only asked how to call the base class constructor from the inherited class and thus I havent't copy-pasted the whole snippet, I only modified the constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

`this.prototype` is undefined, because no one defined it.

`Cat` is a function. As such, it has a property `prototype`. That's mandated by the ECMAScript standard.

`this` is an object that is not a function. As such, the ECMAScript standard does not mandate that it has a  `prototype` property.

If `this` is a `Cat` (i.e. an object that was or is created using `new Cat`), then it has, *for the sake of specification*, an internal `[[Prototype]]` property which is a `Mamal`. But this mamal is not accessible directly (as implied by the word *internal*). When you say `var maru = new Cat()`, then `maru.[[Prototype]]` is linked to `Cat.prototype`. That's how `maru` knows about future methods of mamals.